# Accessing and Interpreting Principal Components

Tags: r, pca

I have performed PCA in R (using the prcomp() function) on returns data of 5 variables.
This is my code:

```
pca1 = prcomp(~df.var1+df.var2+df.var3+df.var4+df.var5, data = ccy)
```

I would like to move to the interpretation stage...the "rotation" matrix in the "pca1" object comprises, to my understanding, the coefficients assigned to each of the original 5 variables in the equation describing the principal component (PC). [This link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/54) suggests calculating the correlations between the PCs and each of the variables. Is the "x" object within the "pca1" object (accessed using:

```
pcs = pca1$x
```

) a matrix of values for the PCs? If I calculated correlations between these values and the original variables, would that represent the correlation between the PCs and the variables? Is there perhaps a "built-in" method for this?

Comment: Here's a rather good guide on `prcomp`: https://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

Comment: @AdamQuek I couldn't find a mention in that article of whether the "x" object within the prcomp object is the values of the principal components and whether, therefore, I can use the values to calculate correlations.